# can you please help me to identify this smd component marked M 412 727a?

Tags: identification, components, surface-mount

Hi please help me identify this smd component marked M 412 727a thanx[image]

Comment: Can you tell us a little bit about what the board is that you show?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Micrel (now Microchip) optocoupler?

Comment: cheers nice one !

Comment: I think Bruce Abbott has the correct answer.

Comment: That logo is Matsushita, for sure. Also Micrel never made optocouplers, so it's not a great guess.

Comment: Would Micropac have been a better guess???

Comment: well, a solid-state relay is (often) a kind of optocoupler,

Answer (score 7):

It's an [AQY412S](https://www3.panasonic.biz/ac/e_download/control/relay/photomos/catalog/semi_eng_gu1b_aqy41_s.pdf?via=ok) "PhotoMOS' solid state relay, manufactured by [Panasonic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Panasonic) (formerly known as Matsushita Electric Industrial Co).

Datasheet says,

> Note: For space reasons, the three initial letters of the part number
>   “AQY”, the surface mount terminal shape indicator “S” and the packing
>   style indicator “X” or “Z” are not marked on the device. (**Ex. the**
>   **label for product number AQY412SX is 412**)

Product photo from [here](https://nz.element14.com/panasonic-electric-works/aqy412sx/mosfet-relay-spst-nc-0-5a-60vac/dp/2894782)

[image]

Comment: Which is why it is labeled RY100 on the board (RY for relay).